# Can a Creature with Multiattack use it on an Opportunity Attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, opportunity-attack

I am familiar with both concepts in D&D 5E — an opportunity attack allows the creature to take one reaction to make an attack; a multiattack allows monsters with the ability to take a number of attacks specified in the description on a single attack action.

But does multiattack apply to opportunity attacks taken on a reaction, or do you just use one of the creature's attacks?

My group is split on this. I think they are able to apply multiattacks, but some of my players disagreed, and frankly, I can see an argument for either way.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No, an opportunity attack is a single melee attack.

From the Player's Basic Rules, page 74:

> To
>   make the opportunity attack, you use your reaction
>   to make **one melee attack** against the provoking
>   creature.

Additionally, multiattack specifies that it can't be used in this way. From the DM Basic Rules, page 6:

> A creature that can make multiple attacks on its
>   turn has the Multiattack ability. A creature can’t use
>   Multiattack when making an opportunity attack, which
>   must be a single melee attack.

Multiattack can be used only on the creature's turn, and it explicitly can't be used with opportunity attacks.

Finally, if you look at the statblock of a creature that *has* Multiattack, you can see that it is listed under the Actions section of the statblock. Multiattack is a specific action that a creature can take, just like a player can take the Attack action or the Use An Object action. Just like a Fighter's Extra Attack, you can't use it every time you make an attack. A Fighter can only use Extra Attack when they take the Attack action, and a creature can only use Multiattack when it takes the Multiattack action.

Comment: This answer is confirmed/reiterated in the [2019 Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf).

Answer (score 9):

From the definition:

> **Multiattack**
>
> A creature that can make multiple attacks on its
>   turn has the Multiattack ability. **A creature can’t use
>   Multiattack when making an opportunity attack, which
>   must be a single melee attack.**

My emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

The only monster that I know of that can use Multiattack as a reaction is the [Duergar Hammerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/duergar-hammerer) (MToF, p. 188).

> ***Engine of Pain.*** Once per turn, a creature that attacks the
>   hammerer can target the duergar trapped inside it. The attacker has
>   disadvantage on the attack roll. On a hit the attacker deals an extra
>   5 (1d10) damage to the hammerer, and the hammerer can respond by using
>   its Multiattack with its reaction.

That is a specific case though, and as other answers have stated, the general rule is no.

Comment: It's worth noting that this reaction Multiattack is not an opportunity attack (though it is a unique way to use Multiattack as a reaction).

Comment: The Duergar Screamer has the same feature. Although I don't understand how this feature works, it sounds good.